# How can I map values submitted from my from to ViewModel with different property names?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I have a form in my razor view which have input fields named `infoName`, `infoId`, ...:

```
<form id="studentInfo" name="studentInfo" action="..." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="infoId" id="infoId" >
    <input type="text" name="infoName" id="infoName" >
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

I had to add `info` prefix to field names of above Form to avoid collisions in my HTML.

I have a controller like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(ViewModel formSubmittedViewModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

And my view model is as below:

```
public class ViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Student Id")]
    [JsonProperty("studentId")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cannot be empty")]
    public string Id{ get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [JsonProperty("studentName")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be empty")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

}
```

As you can see fields in my ViewModel and HTML form have different names.

Are there any methods for mapping them togheter(like what `JsonProperty` of Json.Net does)?

I've looked for stuff like `[Bind(Prefix:"")]` but it cannot be used on properties.

Comment: So if you only have simple properties (not nested or complex ) one then `[BindParameter("infoId")]` does not work?

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar `BindParamter` does not work for properties compiler error says.